# Do muggles react the same way to potions in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, magical-items

For example, if a muggle drank Felix Felicis and went to Las Vegas, would be win every game he played? How about the other potions such as the engorgement charm seen in Book 2, or the skelegrow? Would muggles be able to grow back their skeleton?

Is there any mention of muggles using wizard potions in any of the books?

Comment: ...And, if yes, why aren't these bastards helping us out when we break our bones or lose our limbs? What kind of Prime Directive nonsense is that?

Comment: @MishaRosnach There's probably a question on that elsewhere. The gist of it is that it's not a Prime Directive, but a Masquerade: both the Wizarding World and the Muggle World live in highly evolved enviroments, but the Wizarding World has decided to hide themselves from the Muggle World because increased reliance on technology and science has made Muggles become distrustful of magic. That's why about 424 years ago, the Wizarding World has decided to hide itself from the Muggle World to avoid literal Witch Hunts.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Possibly Yes.

Tom Riddle Senior was a muggle, and according to Dumbledore he could have been affected by a love potion, just like if he were a wizard. Maybe not all potions work exactly the same to wizards and muggles, but we have at least one example.

From the Half-Blood Prince, chapter 10

> "The Imperius Curse?" Harry suggested. "Or a love potion?"
>  Albus Dumbledore: "Very good.
>  Personally, I am inclined to think that she used a love potion. I am
>  sure it would have seemed more romantic to her, and I do not think it
>  would have been very difficult, some hot day, when Riddle was riding
>  alone, to persuade him to take a drink of water.
>   (...)
>  "Again, this is guesswork," said Dumbledore, "but I believe that
>  Merope, who was deeply in love with her husband, could not bear to
>  continue enslaving him by magical means. I believe that she made the
>  choice to stop giving him the potion"...